# Filling XFA PDF with iText7 and then flattening results in error

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm opening a fillable PDF, then filling it through XML and saving it. This works OK, it outputs a PDF with the forms filled, albeit it's read-only now:

```
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Temp\2.pdf");
        pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
        var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"C:\Temp\3.pdf");
        var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

        try
        {
            var acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

            var xfa = acroForm.GetXfaForm();           

            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/");

            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, data, ns);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using var xmlReader = new StreamReader(memStream);

            var xmlString = await xmlReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var updatedMemStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString));
            
            xfa.FillXfaForm(updatedMemStream);
            
            xfa.Write(pdfDoc);
        }
        finally
        {
            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
            pdfWriter.Close();
        }
```

I want to flatten this PDF further so that it can be opened with normal PDF viewers:

```
        var destFile = new MemoryStream();
        var xfaFlattener = new XFAFlattener();
        xfaFlattener.Flatten(new MemoryStream( await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"C:\Temp\3.pdf")), destFile);
        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(@"C:\Temp\4.pdf", destFile.ToArray());
```

But when running this I get this odd error:

```
AbstractITextEvent is only for internal usage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the PDF and data to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: also, XFAFlattener is part of [pdfXFA](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/flatten-pdf-pdfxfa). Do you have a license loaded for this product?

Comment: @mkl yes it's this file: https://cfr.forms.gov.ab.ca/Form/CDEV0005.pdf

Comment: @AndréLemos at the moment I'm trialing to see if iText7 can do what I need, but the exception would be odd if it was a licensing issue right?

Comment: indeed. Which versions/packages are you loading?

Comment: itext7 8.0.0, itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter 8.0.0 and itext7.pdfxfa 4.0.0. This is in a .NET7 application running on Windows.

Comment: it's possible that pdfXFA is not possible with .NET 7. let me look into it

Comment: @RogerFar, I'm afraid that pdfXFA is not compatible with .NET 7. What some of our customers do, is to containerize this functionality, or create a CLI. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks @AndréLemos, so pdfXFA needs iTextSharp or iText5? Or is it a matter of using .NET 4.8 instead of .NET Core?

Comment: iTextSharp is just the .NET version of iText 5. You can use pdfXFA with iText 5 (Java/.NET) or ideally with iText 8 (Java/.NET). wrt. a specific .NET version, we currently only run tests for .NET Framework (4.7?), I'm afraid.